# python httplib snippet

Tags: python

I've written this snippet to extract a review request status from review-board in python. It works well but i'm very new to python and i would like to know if i could write this any better.
Should i put `conn.close` in it's own try statement ?

This script is supposed to run as part of a post-commit hook in mercurial.
If the review-board server is not responding i still want to be able to commit without any issues. If the commit is non existent then an empty string is ok.

```
import httplib
import json

def getReviewStatus(reviewboardUrl, id):
    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(reviewboardUrl, 80)
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
        conn.request("GET", "/api/review-requests/%s/" % id, headers=headers)
        return json.loads(conn.getresponse().read())['review_request']['status']
    except:
        return ""
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: is this a standalone script? if so I'd let it blow on errors, don't catch any exceptions (specially don't *silently* catch *all* exceptions)

Comment: i amended my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty good to me. Regarding `conn.close()`, definitely don't put this in its own `try` statement, because if there's a problem with the earlier code, the connection might not get closed. I know you're not using Python 3, but ss an alternative, you might consider using the `with` statement and let Python handle the closing for you. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects (end of section) and http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing

Your code might look like this:

```
import httplib
import json
from contextlib import closing

def getReviewStatus(reviewboardUrl, id):
    try:
        with closing(httplib.HTTPConnection(reviewboardUrl, 80)) as conn:
            headers = {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            }
            conn.request("GET", "/api/review-requests/%s/" % id, headers=headers)
            return json.loads(conn.getresponse().read())['review_request']['status']
    except:
        return ""
```

I find it's good to get into the habit of using `with` to open resources so don't have to worry about forgetting to close the connection.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what i had in mind ! Thanks a bunch !! i knew about `with` but i didn't knew about `from contextlib import closing`, absolutely brilliant !

Comment: Out of interest, what would happen with this code if the `requests` throws an exception and the implicit `close` call throws an exception as well ?

Comment: That's a good question! This would be difficult to test. Maybe ask on Stack Overflow? I personally have never seen an exception thrown while trying to close a file/socket. Are you getting one, or just trying to code defensively?

Comment: just trying to be defensive :)